# Can i create a list column that has a view icon much like the edit icon?

Tags: list, form, view, item

Hi and thanks in advance for any answers provided:)
Im very new to sharepoint so please forgive my ignorance.
I am currently using Sharepoint 365.

I am trying to find a way to view an item in a list that returns all the column data for that item. I would like the result to be in the same format as would be returned if you were to click on the edit icon in the list but in view only mode.

Do you know if there is a way to create a similar icon as the edit icon in a list for view only mode as this would be ideal?

If i can't create the icon perhaps there is something i can do with creating a view form. I thought about creating a new view form using sharepoint designer, but sharepoint creates the new form with a relationship to the 1st item in the list.

If i was to use the new form option how would I associate the new form to a particular item in the list where a user clicks on an item or link to that item. 
I hope this makes some sort of sense.
P.S. I don't have InfoPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different we can achieve this. You can use out of the box View Item page for displaying the item. You need to make sure you are passing the correct item id as a query string parameter to that page.

In the list view using JavaScript/jQuery you can add a dynamic column and embed the image into it along with `a` tag. Populate the `href` to have the same URL as the view item page and populate the item id by reading it from the HTML objects.

If you are on 2013 then you can make use of CSR.

Another option is to create a calculated field that emits the HTML. It should create the link to the view page something like

```
'<a href="viewpagepath.aspx?id="' + [ID] + '"><img src="imagepath.png"/></a>'
```

Comment: Two remarks: A. The calculated column needs to be se to a datatype **other** then Text for this to work. B. Since the ``[ID]`` value is set **after** the Calculated Column Formulas are evaluated, the value will be 0 for New items.